# apache2 with mod_mono cannot be started. Error: undefined symbol: unixd_config

Tags: c#, apache, ubuntu, mono, mod-mono

after installing mono from source and the steps to install mod_mono here http://r2d2.cc/2014/03/25/asp-net-mvc-under-linux-with-mono/ i ended with:

apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_mono.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mono.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mono.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config

on my ubuntu linux 14.10. I tried install mono-complete first, with the same error, than i tried to install from github sources. mono is working fine (c# console test), but when i try to start the apache2 server, i get this error.

Line 140 is the line where the mono_load is called. All files seems to be there. i tried to google and find the issue - but now, after 5h this is my last hope...

Does someone have an idea what i can do?

thanks for your help!
mike.

Answer (score 7):

Just a very late followup to this question as I ran into the same error today on Ubuntu 16.04 after `mod_mono` upgraded. When searching the error, this is the first result that comes up, so I figured I'd update with what fixed it for me:

While previously, one installed the Debian 7 repos/packages for `mod_mono` to use with Ubuntu, apparently there is now an Ubuntu repo. Removing the Debian 7 repos and replacing with the Ubuntu 16.04 repos solved the issue.

Here's the link to the repos:

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-ubuntu

Comment: Same problem/ similar solution on Debian - it seems they finally made a repository for jessie

Answer (score 0):

The module was not ported to work with apache 2.4.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/new_api_2_4.html

```
unixd_config
This has been renamed to ap_unixd_config.

unixd_setup_child()
This has been renamed to ap_unixd_setup_child(), but most callers should call the added ap_run_drop_privileges() hook.
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much covener. you brought me to the right track. After investigating i found out that this is not completely true.
If someone else is running into these issues - it seems that it something to do with ubuntu. I changed to debian 7, made an upgrade to jessie and used apache 2.4.10 with mod_mono there. and... its working!
I gave ubuntu a try again, but didnt make it work. So im on debian 7.9 (8) now and everything is fine.
Very strange. anyway. thanks. mike.